# Davening in which Beis Medrash?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, synagogue

Must one pray in the Beis Medrash he learns or in *any* Beis Medrash (and the practical difference would be if there's an advantage in the other Beis Medrash, such as if it's further  away and there's Schar Pesiyos)

The [Gemara](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=8&format=text) says

> אמר ליה רבא לרפרם בר פפא לימא לן מר מהני מילי מעלייתא דאמרת משמיה דרב חסדא במילי דבי כנישתא אמר ליה הכי אמר רב חסדא מאי דכתי' אוהב ה' שערי ציון מכל משכנות יעקב אוהב ה' שערים המצויינים בהלכה יותר מבתי כנסיות ומבתי מדרשות

Rav Chisda said that the verse "Hashem loves the gates of Zion more than all the dwelling places of Yaakov" teaches that Hashem loves the gates of Halacha more than the synagogues and study halls.

Which implies that one should pray where **people** study (**Halacha**).

והיינו דאמר ר' חייא בר אמי משמיה דעולא מיום שחרב בית המקדש אין לו להקב"ה בעולמו אלא ארבע אמות של הלכה בלבד.

> Rabbi Chiya said that since the Beis Hamikdash was destroyed, Hashem only had the four cubits of Halacha (which implies that one should pray where **people** study)

On the other hand,

ואמר אביי מריש הוה גריסנא בגו ביתא ומצלינא בבי כנישתא כיון דשמענא להא דאמר רבי חייא בר אמי משמיה דעולא מיום שחרב בית המקדש אין לו להקב"ה בעולמו אלא ארבע אמות של הלכה בלבד לא הוה מצלינא אלא היכא דגריסנא.

Abaye said that he used to learn at home and pray at the synagogue, but since he heard Rabbi Chiya's teaching, he only prayed where he studied.

Which implies one should pray where **he** studies

רבי אמי ורבי אסי אף על גב דהוו להו תליסר בי כנישתא בטבריא לא מצלו אלא ביני עמודי היכא דהוו גרסי

So if there are two Batei Medrash, one (in which he learns) close by and the other a distance away, where should one pray?

Answer (score 2):

In the Shulchan Aruch's formulation of this halacha ([O.C. 90:18](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x460)), he speaks of a בית מדרש קבוע, a fixed beis medrash. Nothing about your learning there or any personal connection to it.

However, the Rema (ibid) adds in the one word לו, to him, in his formulation - a beis medrash that is fixed to *him*. This implies that it is your set beis medrash that you frequent which is being discussed.